# Python Azure sdk: How to retrieve secrets from keyvault?

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I need to retrieve secrets from keyvault. This is my code so far:

```
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials


subscription_id = 'x'
# See above for details on creating different types of AAD credentials
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'x',
    secret = 'x',
    tenant = 'x'
)

kv_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for vault in kv_client.vaults.list():
    print(vault)
```

But I am getting this error:

> msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error:
>   AuthorizationFailed Message: The client 'x' with object id 'x' does
>   not have authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resources/read' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/x'.

Now I am able to access the same keyvault with same credentials using C# code/ POwershell so there is definitely nothing wrong with authorization. Not sure why it isnt working using SDK. Please help.

Comment: No idea, the Bearer token may have the wrong audience in or something along those lines - try asking in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues if you're sure the SPN is good for that resource. Try to find a way to turn on tracing, maybe it hints you about what's in the token.

Comment: Your code works for me, I could list secrets in the key vault. If possible, could you give your service principal `Owner` pernission and try again. [Assign application to role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Comment: Also, you could give `Contributer ` permission, it also works for me. It is very strange, I am not sure why the service principal works on C# and PowerShell. But, I suggest you could check and try give permission.

Comment: What's the specific azure python you're using? I assume you are using the latest one which is 2.0.0rc6

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to access via a `ServicePrincipalCredentials` instance, you can just use:

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient, KeyVaultAuthentication
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

credentials = None

def auth_callback(server, resource, scope):
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = '',
        secret = '',
        tenant = '',
        resource = "https://vault.azure.net"
    )
    token = credentials.token
    return token['token_type'], token['access_token']

client = KeyVaultClient(KeyVaultAuthentication(auth_callback))

secret_bundle = client.get_secret("https://vault_url", "secret_id", "")

print(secret_bundle.value)
```

This assumes that you don't want to pass a version. If you do, you can substitute the last parameter for it.

Comment: I am trying with the same code and getting `AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 404`.

Answer (score 4):

I run your code sample above and it is able to list the key vaults without any issue, hence it is not a code issue.

I have assigned the **Contributor** role to my AD application on the subscription where the key vault is provisioned and set the Access Policies to allow GET & LIST permissions for Key and Secret to the AD application.

The versions of my Azure Python packages used running under **Python 3.6.2** runtime environment:

- **azure.common (1.1.8)**
- **azure.mgmt.keyvault (0.40.0)**
- **msrestazure(0.4.13)**

I'll recommend you to try on the Python runtime version and Azure Python packages versions which is verified working.

**Addendum:**

If the above Python runtime environment version as well as Azure Python packages also does not work for you, you should probably consider creating a new issue in the [Azure SDK for Python GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues) as it is working with the same credential with Azure .NET SDK as well as PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get secret by the name of the secret instead of ID:

`secret_bundle = client.get_secret(<VAULT URL>, "<NAME>", "")`

Answer (score 2):

There are some good answers already, but the Azure SDK has since released new packages for working with Key Vault in Python that replace `azure-keyvault`:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/migration_guide.md)

[azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) is also the package that should be used with these for authentication.

Documentation for working with the secrets library can be found on the [azure-sdk-for-python GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/README.md), and here's a sample for retrieving secrets as you were doing:

```python
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

secret_client = SecretClient(
    vault_url="https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/",
    credential=credential
)
secret = secret_client.get_secret("secret-name")
```

You can provide the same credentials that you used for `ServicePrincipalCredentials` by setting environment variables corresponding to the `client_id`, `secret`, and `tenant`:

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID="client_id"
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="secret"
export AZURE_TENANT_ID="tenant"
```

(I work on the Azure SDK in Python)

Answer (score 1):

> One can use the below class from azure.identity i.e **ClientSecretCredential**, find the below code ex: snippet

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

TENANT= <TenantId-in-string>
CLIENT_ID = <ClientId-in-string>
CLIENT_SECRET= <ClientSecret-in-string>
credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
VAULT_URL= <AzureVault-url-in-string>
client = SecretClient(vault_url=VAULT_URL, credential=credential)

print(client)
example_secret = client.get_secret(<secret_name_in_string>)
print(example_secret.value)
```